# R SQL Server file does not exist error - but it does

Tags: sql, r, nlp, udpipe

I'm running R 3.5.2 inside SQL Server 2019.

Loading the pre-trained udpipe model using the following command:

```
udmodel_english <- udpipe_load_model(file = ''C:/ud/english-ewt-ud-2.5-191206.udpipe'')
```

This works fine in Rstudio, and R directly. However when running as a SQL External script I get the following error:

```
Error in udpipe_load_model(file = "C:/ud/english-ewt-ud-2.5-191206.udpipe") : 
  File C:/ud/english-ewt-ud-25-191206.udpipe containing the language model does not exist
Calls: source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> udpipe_load_model
```

However the file is there, it does exist, and loads via Rstudio with no issue.

Any suggestions would be extremely helpful.

Full code as FYI:

```
Begin
EXEC sp_execute_external_script       
@language = N'R',
@script = N' 

library(zoo)
library(xts)
library(udpipe)

#model <- udpipe_download_model(language = "english")
udmodel_english <- udpipe_load_model(file = ''C:/ud/english-ewt-ud-2.5-191206.udpipe'')
'
End
```

Full error as FYI:

```
Msg 39004, Level 16, State 20, Line 29
A 'R' script error occurred during execution of 'sp_execute_external_script' with HRESULT 0x80004004.
Msg 39019, Level 16, State 2, Line 29
An external script error occurred: 

Attaching package: 'zoo'

The following objects are masked from 'package:base':

    as.Date, as.Date.numeric

Error in udpipe_load_model(file = "C:/ud/english-ewt-ud-2.5-191206.udpipe") : 
  File C:/ud/english-ewt-ud-25-191206.udpipe containing the language model does not exist
Calls: source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> udpipe_load_model
In addition: Warning messages:
1: package 'zoo' was built under R version 3.5.3 
2: package 'xts' was built under R version 3.5.3 
3: package 'udpipe' was built under R version 3.5.3 

Error in execution.  Check the output for more information.
Error in eval(ei, envir) : 
  Error in execution.  Check the output for more information.
Calls: runScriptFile -> source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> .Call
Execution halted
```

Thanks

Comment: Does a remote SQL Server normally have full access to your local hard drive?

Comment: @r2evans with the R SQL Server, i would say yes. You can directly import/export data from the local drive to the server

Comment: Yes, the SQL Server has access to the SQL Server's `C:\\` drive. There is nothing in the OP that suggests that RStudio is being on the SQL Server itself, it is generally safe to assume (yes, I know it's just an assumption) that RStudio is connecting to the remote host. If the OP is running both RStudio and the DBMS itself on the same computer, then that makes sense. If not, then having a *remote* SQL Server being able to access *my local drive* is counter-intuitive (and a security problem ... *<puts on tin-foil hat>*).

Comment: Yeah, SQL Server can normally access drive. I also added "Full Control" permission on the C:/ud folder to SQLRUserGroup, SQLServer2005SQLBrowserUser, SQLServerMSASUUser explicitly just in case.

Comment: SQL Server is installed on my local machine with R services.

Comment: Also just "Everyone" full read/write to that folder. Still same error.

Comment: I'm going to guess that the path is being passed as-is without normalizing to windows-specific backslashing. Try changing from `="c:/ud/..."` to `="c:\\ud\\..."` and see if it works.

Comment: Also, I don't have a SQL Server instance with R available, but the script has a significant number of single-quotes; some of that is due to how SQL Server wants the string, I wonder if there are interactions on unmatched or unmasked single-quotes. (It would likely result in a syntax error instead of file not found, but ... just a thought.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done it.  (Finally!!)

Yes, it was a permissions issue, but not like you would expect. Aside from SQL having access to the folder, to have R access a file folder outside of working directory. You have to give permissions to "ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES" object to that folder.

Hope that saves anyone else the hours of piecing together google bits.